# Automatic a Web Page to Run Daily

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, automation

I'm very unfamiliar with this, I've heard about running sql automated jobs, but how Can I run an aspx page daily?? Basically When the page loads up, it constructs an email and sends it out..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jacob

Answer (score 0):

you could create a scheduled task which invokes that page with a WebRequest, is this what you want? Is it enough to access the page with a request as it would happen opening it with the browser or do you need to insert some values in some fields and click a button for example?

Comment: I do not need to worry about giving it any values...But making a button click on its own would be helpful.